# GCP Postgresql instance performance becomes unusably slow after a few days

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, graphql, sequelize.js

I've deployed a Postgresql instance w/ Sequelize and graphql to GCP.  For the first 6 months of usage I noticed no problems in performance.  But recently I've noticed that the instance will hit a wall in terms of performance.  Queries will time out after 25s+ - this will happen to many queries - it is not occurring on a single, specific query.  Strangely, the performance returns back to normal when I redeploy a new instance, even if the code for that instance is the exact same the one that saw the performance degradation.

I've checked https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/diagnose-issues and nothing there seems to be the issue.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.
TY

Comment: memory leaks? Does a simple reloading also help?

Comment: Hmm maybe, though I would figure that the performance degradation would be more gradual. Next time I notice the issue, I'll try simply restarting the instance, TY!

Comment: Did restarting solve the issue? If not, you can contact GCP support, you need to figure out if this GCP or Postgres related issue.